# Listen Paste event System wide

Tags: android, global, paste, listen

I need to listen to system wide copy/paste events

For system wide copy event i am using ClipBoardManager's addPrimaryClipChangedListener but i dont know how to listen system wide paste event.

Any help is appreciated

Edit:
As mentioned by CommonsWare Paste is not an event which we can listen 
So can we just listen to clipboard instead whenever an app accesses it without changing it we can know that its an paste event

Comment: include the code to show your own work and effort taken by you in order to solve this problem.

Comment: rigth now instead of listening to copy and paste event to trigger a service i used event of copying the same text twice in a minite and i had inform user qbout this in app tour

Answer (score 0):

There is no "paste event" in Android. Hence, you cannot listen for it.

Comment: so can't i listen to clipboard ? like onPrimaryClipChangesListener does ? just instead of changing clipboard i need to check if anyone accesses it (i.e. paste event)

Comment: @NISHANTDESAI: "So can we just listen to clipboard instead whenever an app accesses it" -- no.